# Android PopupMenu clipped to boundaries of ActionBar

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am trying to create a PopupMenu in an Android application. Since the main window of the app makes only minimal use of Android layout elements (essentially it is a large graphic), I use the following code in the main Activity:

```
public void showMenu() {
    View v = this.getCurrentFocus();
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    this.prepareMenu(popup.getMenu()); // populate menu with items
    popup.show();
}
```

The method gets called when the user touches a particular region of the screen.

The menu displays on top of the ActionBar but does not extend beyond its boundaries. I can scroll through the menu (thus the items are there), but I can't figure out how to get the menu to extend beyond the boundaries of the ActionBar.

The app has a fullscreen mode, which hides the ActionBar. When I do this, the menu does not show at all. Log output shows me that `showMenu()` gets called on the first touch but not on the second, indicating that the menu does open, albeit hidden or off-screen, and gets dismissed on the second touch.

When I inspect the values reported by `v.getMeasuredHeight()` and `v.getMeasuredWidth()`, I get something close to the screen size of my device (height varies depending on ActionBar visibility), indicating I'm dealing with a view that occupies most of the screen.

I've tried tinkering around with gravity (such as `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP | Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);`) but to no avail. I can switch the menu position from top-left to top-right that way but the size is always the same.

I've also tried various ways of obtaining a view to anchor the menu to, as in

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
while ((window != null) && (window.getContainer() != null))
    window = window.getContainer();
View v = window.getDecorView();
```

but the only difference is that for some views the menu does not show at all. When it does, it always extends over the full height of the ActionBar and is always clipped at the bottom end.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a possible reason for this behavior. Apparently the PopupMenu never obstructs its associated View. Since in my case the associated View takes up the entire space, that leaves only the ActionBar for the menu. When the action bar is hidden, there is literally nowhere to place the menu.

Thus the solution would be to create a dummy View as an anchor for the menu. There are two possibilities for those:

- A transparent View which floats on top of the main View. This would allow placing the menu virtually anywhere on the main View, with the only limitation that it cannot be aligned with the top or bottom edge (as the anchor would separate it from the edge).
- A View with zero height or width, placed at the edge of the main View. This would align the menu with the respective edge., Using Gravity, the menu could be placed in a corner of the main View. Though I'm not sure if Android allows dimensions of a View to be zero.

I'll need to do some more testing to find out.

Comment: Turns out there is a much simpler way to achieve what I wanted – specifically, to show the Options menu. Rather than creating a popup menu with the same content, I found I can simply call `openOptionsMenu()` from the Activity. The menu will show in a default position, which is OK for me, and it will extend potentially along the full screen height (excluding system bars).